# JMeter to synchronize login and other request

Tags: timer, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

There is a thread group, which contains login request and after that posting of a form. In some cases I get error message in response of form posting request, that user isn't logged in. I use `Synchronizing Timer` in both HTTP requests(group by=20). Thread is a `Stepping Thread Group`, so number of active users is incremented in more steps.

[image: Stepping thread group]

Answer (score 1):

No matter whether you use the Synchronizing Timer or not it shouldn't cause any problem with logging in because each thread (virtual user) executes Samplers upside down and separately from the others, the Synchronizing Timer acts as a [rendezvous-vous point](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/LoadRunner/What_is_a_rendezvous_point_.html) for multiple users and each of them has its own authentication context.

So the problem with failed login is somewhere else, I would recommend re-running your test with [Debug Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) added and enabled [storing of requests and response data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter/) so you could inspect the flow and determine the reason for the sporadic login failures.